# Adding echo row inside of include statement

Tags: php, include

Can I pull data from mySQL into include statement so it will open whatever URL I place into field "theme"

```
<?php include("<? echo $rows['theme']; ?>"); ?>
```

I want to add this to index.php and I have a editable form where I can add any URL to field theme. Can someone help me get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
// here you are already inside the php tags so you don't need any others
include($rows['theme']); // you don't need to echo anything just pass the value 
?>
```

However i would recommend you use a switch statement to check the value on $rows['theme']

Comment: I getting the following error:  Warning: include() [function.include]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in...  sure why, i use include throughout the site, works just fine.

Comment: that is because you probably trying to do something like include("http://google.com") witch is *not* the way it should be used
only use include to load php files from your local server something like include("header.php")
if you need to load css and js use the link and script html tag

Comment: I see, I added http://, now Im getting another error: Warning: include(pictures/picturetheme/defult14/theme.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory. under theme field i have the following data /picturetheme/defult14/theme.php This URL work when type it in the browser.  thanks

Comment: the path you provide to the include must be relative to the php file you are editing, not the root of your site, so make sure the path is ok

Comment: oh! thanks for your help... any alternative to include? i wanted to use  PHP redirection, but I cant add server info or make the url dynamical pull from MySQL?

Comment: np, if the answer helped don't forget to accept it. include is used to load a part of your code like header, footer, you can read more about it in the docs http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
so depending on what you want to achieve you might find your answer there

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
<?php include($rows['theme']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
<?php
    $theme = $rows['theme'].".php";
    include($theme);
?>
```

But you should validate input if it's coming from user.